# Throw an exception into another thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, exception, posix

This is not a duplicate of any question involving catching an exception thrown in one thread from another.

I have code which spawns a thread, and it goes off and does its own thing.

At some point in the future, I'd like to be able to throw one of two exceptions in the other thread (i.e. `terminate` and `interrupt`).

One way to do this is to have a variable shared and have the other thread periodically check if it should be killed. My preference is to not have the constraint that it checks (some of the code will be independent of the library doing the threading and won't have been written to check).

In my ideal solution, you may end up in a situation where, debugging, you might find that `auto i = 1 + 1` throws an exception because another thread told your thread to throw and that's the line you just *happened* to be on at the time.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: This really just doesn't make any sense to be honest. C++'s exception mechanism is fundamentally organized around unwinding the stack of the context in which the exception occurred. Perhaps you could try explaining the problem you seek to solve with this mechanism and you'll get suggestions for sensible ways to solve it. The usual answer is this: "If you find you need to reach in from the outside to make a thread do the right thing, that means you wrote the code for that thread wrong. Why isn't it coded to do the right thing already? All threads *must* cooperate."

Comment: In an ideal world, yes, @DavidSchwartz, they would. But if one thread is waiting for some API (e.g. InfiniBand) to return and it never does, it doesn't matter if all there ads *should* cooperate: they don't. Assuming you'll always be in a position like that is naive.

Comment: There are definitely tools for handling cases like that, but cross-thread exceptions aren't them. If the API supports interruption, you'd just use the interruption it supported. And if it didn't support interruption, then interrupting wouldn't be the solution. Otherwise, you have to use other tools, such as isolating the API to its own process with a wrapper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to raise an exception into another thread.

I'm going to assume you know all the good reasons why this should not be done in a normal program.   But as a part of, say, a test suite, a debug tool, or a program that is otherwise concerned with python internals, this might be helpful.

This is lifted, roughly from https://gist.github.com/liuw/2407154

```
import ctypes

def ctype_async_raise(target_tid, exception):
    ret = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(ctypes.c_long(target_tid), ctypes.py_object(exception))
    # ref: http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc
    if ret == 0:
        raise ValueError("Invalid thread ID")
    elif ret > 1:
        # Huh? Why would we notify more than one threads?
        # Because we punch a hole into C level interpreter.
        # So it is better to clean up the mess.
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(target_tid, NULL)
        raise SystemError("PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc failed")
```

Comment: Is it possible to raise an exception in another thread under C++?  AFAICT the questioner didn't mention python.

Comment: In c++ it's so easy I didn't even notice... 
 pthread_kill(threadObject, ...)... it will send a signal

Comment: Hmm, pthread_kill() sends a signal; presumably the signal-receiving would need to have some mechanism to convert the signal-handler callback into a raised C++ exception.  I don't think you can just call `throw` from within a signal-handler, though.

Comment: @ErikAronesty Can you elaborate why it shouldn't be done? Raising InterruptedException in another thread is an essential way to terminate threads in Java, for example.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think it makes conceptual sense to have an exception in thread A be caught in thread B, since a central concept of an exception is the unwinding of the stack, and thread A's stack is different from thread B's stack.

What you could do is throw the exception in thread A, have an exception handler in thread A catch the exception and handle it by somehow notifying thread B with the relevant details, and when thread B receives the notification is could respond by throwing its own exception that was similar to the exception originally thrown in thread A.

As for how to implement that notification and data transfer, you could use any of the usual cross-thread notification/communications mechanisms (shared atomic variables and polling, socketpair, pipe, mutex-guarded FIFO message queues, etc).

> In my ideal solution, you may end up in a situation where, debugging,
>   you might find that auto i = 1 + 1 throws an exception because another
>   thread told your thread to throw and that's the line you just happened
>   to be on at the time.

I think that is known as an asynchronous exception, and I don't think it is supported by standard C++.  Microsoft has their [structured exception handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de5awhsw.aspx) (SEH) that sort of does that, but that's a proprietary/non-standard feature.

Comment: With the exception of your last paragraph, I think you completely missed the point. There *are* lots of ways to get something from one thread to another - if the other is listening. But if the other thread isn't listening (because somebody wrote an API that blocks on something and doesn't wait), it doesn't matter. And the point isn't to throw an exception in one thread and catch it in the other: it's to inject a thread into another thread.

Comment: Would it be better to change my answer to "no, it's not possible"?  (btw, the title of the question is "Throw an exception into another thread", which sounds an awful lot like "throw an exception in one thread and catch it in the other" to me)

Comment: It sounds like it, but not really. One is `throw Exception()` followed by a catch in the other thread. The other is `otherThreadObject.throwException<Exception>()`

Comment: The OP specifically states that they are not looking for this in their question: "This is not a duplicate of any question involving catching an exception thrown in one thread from another." I agree that the scenario you describe makes no sense, but I think that is why the OP isn't asking about it.